# Fail loading Mssql PHP driver with 64 bit WAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I need to know how to use the php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll driver with 64 bit WAMP.

I need to use PDO MSSQL driver with Yii framework and my WAMP version is 64 bit.

I know the 32 bit version will work, but I can't uninstall/install WAMP.

When I try to load the driver, I see this in the Apache error log:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: There's a comment on php.net regarding this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

How did you solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't solve it. I simply uninstall/install WAMP. Take so many time and other compatibily issues, but it's work now.